# how do you get the permissions of a remote driveItem?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Using the MS Graph REST API, I can retrieve driveItems that are shared with me.  The Permissions of those "remote" driveItems include one identifying me as a user.  However, that Permission object has no "Roles" in it (specifically, the Roles list has zero entries).

I tried looking at the RemoteItem properties, but these do not contain any security info.

What is the correct method to determine what my user's permissions are on that specific DriveItem?

Thus far, I have tested using the C# MSGraph SDK and found all the items shared with me to have an empty Roles list.

I have also used the online Graph Explorer and determined the same to be true.

When I retrieved the actual item using Graph Explorer, note the following in this example snippet from MSFT:

```
        {
        "id": "aTowIy5mfG1lbWJlcnNoaXB8YWxleHdAbTM2NXgyMTQzNTUub25taWNyb3NvZnQuY29t",
        "roles": [],
        "grantedTo": {
            "user": {
                "email": "AlexW@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
                "id": "4782e723-f4f4-4af3-a76e-25e3bab0d896",
                "displayName": "Alex Wilber"
            }
        }
    },
```

(No roles are listed for the user?)

I would have expected, since my User was explicitly listed in one of the Permits of the actual DriveItem retrieved, that the Role would also have specified my access/actual permission.

Comment: What request did you make to get the `permission` without the roles?

Comment: I mentioned it below, but to be clear: Go to Graph Explorer, do not login (or log out) so you're using the default/example account, and click the Shared With Me example (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe).  Take the first DriveItem returned as the example. Use the remoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId and the RemoteItem.Id to make the following permissions call:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!bUbEy-Q7O0yQlf5IKmlRJE8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd/Items/01OMQY4ZIQKYGMW5QLMFB2FHQ7H5N6YUYP/permissions

Answer (score 2):

The following endpoint:

```
GET /drives/{remoteItem-driveId}/items/{remoteItem-id}/permissions
```

returns sharing [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) on a [`DriveItem` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Result

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('b%21IZJbPb0BjUKDAjMnMOSRf44bwdRO75NGunQibG16o65AcVUi0kiOSZ9k4-NxVd6C')/items('01H24BBVK3QUEPTCR2MNB3HMLTNUZINN54')/permissions",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "c0594808-fbbb-4c56-9b62-bc37307a2424",
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "link": {
                "scope": "anonymous",
                "type": "edit",
                "webUrl": "https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/jdoe_contoso_onmicrosoft_com/EVuFCPmKOmNDs7FzbTKGt7wBxdHHpbjDMOzy3_ng2KHCAQ"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "8a03ff0b-5196-4585-b8a9-4d95115e10c2",
            "roles": [
                "read"
            ],
            "link": {
                "scope": "anonymous",
                "type": "view",
                "webUrl": "https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/jdoe_contoso_onmicrosoft_com/EVuFCPmKOmNDs7FzbTKGt7wB8wPZsfAqSd-IQYE337GDjg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "aTowIy5mfG1lbWJlcnNoaXB8dmdyZW1AbWVkaWFkZXY4OC5vbm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20",
            "roles": [
                "owner"
            ],
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "1ee49b6f-4632-4806-a4dd-e065844f9cd1",
                    "displayName": "Jon Doe"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The following example demonstrates how to print [`Permissions` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) `Roles` property via [`msgraph-sdk-dotnet`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet):

```
var item = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[itemId].Request().Expand("Permissions").GetAsync();
foreach (var permission in item.Permissions)
{
    var roleNames = String.Join(", ", permission.Roles.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(roleNames);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that is the documented endpoint.  However, if you actually try that, it'll return something like what I have in my example in the OP.  That is, the Roles are returned as an empty list.  Have you been able to retrieve different results?  Thanks for the post!

Comment: @AWeber, `permissions` endpoint returns the results including roles on my side,  anyway the answer has been updated

Comment: Something is amiss then...If I use Graph Explorer, NOT authenticated and get sharedWithMe, the first item is ID: 01OMQY4ZIQKYGMW5QLMFB2FHQ7H5N6YUYP.  Looking at the RemoteItem and ParentReference, if you try: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!bUbEy-Q7O0yQlf5IKmlRJE8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd/Items/01OMQY4ZIQKYGMW5QLMFB2FHQ7H5N6YUYP/permissions you get something like what I posted???

Comment: @AWeber,  yes, the provided query looks valid, according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) please make sure at least the following permissions are granted : `Files.Read.All, Sites.Read.All`